# Logstash use in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana

Can logstash be used to upload data from the file into kibana?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JRZj8myVu1UHJ3jxZzzb8LSKKMicY0Qi

I have this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move/index the data to `elasticsearch`.
You can use `filebeat/logstash` and migrate the data to `elasticsearch`.

Once the data migration/indexing is done, then you can connect kibana to elasticsearch.
In the `kibana` you need to mention the `elasticsearch` entry.

Once done you could be able to design report/dashboards in `kibana`.